# Libgdx select ModelInstance

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx with custom Model.

Model have got a lot of object (rooms).

I use center of ModelInstance to detect clicked object.

```
Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(screenX, screenY);

        int result = -1;
        float distance = -1;

        Array<Room> instances = buildingContainer.getAllRooms();

        for (int i = 0; i<instances.size ; i++) {
            Room room = instances.get(i);

            if(room.floor == this.last_render_floor && room.is_room) {
                GameObject instance = instances.get(i).model;

                instance.transform.getTranslation(position);
                position.add(instance.center);



                final float len = Math.abs(ray.direction.dot(position.x-ray.origin.x, position.y-ray.origin.y, position.z-ray.origin.z));

                float dist2 = Math.abs(position.dst2(ray.origin.x+ray.direction.x*len, ray.origin.y+ray.direction.y*len, ray.origin.z+ray.direction.z*len));

                if (distance >= 0f && dist2 > distance) 
                    continue;

                if (dist2 <= instance.radius * instance.radius) {
                    result = i;
                    distance = dist2;
                } 

            }

        }
         clicked ++;

        return result;
```

All is OK until, I change camera position.

I selected wrong rooms. I think it is problem with distance with Ray and center of room.

Any sugestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That length calculation looks wrong to me. The length of a vector is the square root of its dot product with itself, so I don't see what the ray direction has to do with it. I would do

```
final float len = tmpVec3.set(position).sub(ray.origin).len();
```

By the way, it's unnecessary to take the absolute value of dst2.

Comment: The length is the square root of dot(x)*dot(x) isn't it?

Comment: The `len` calculation is almost (except for the `abs`) correct (it's vector projection). This code looks like a modified version of http://blog.xoppa.com/interacting-with-3d-objects/. OP: revert the changes you made. If you find the accuracy insufficient, then have a look at the next tutorial (collision shapes) to see how to improve that. You cant expect near perfect accuracy with a ray against bounding sphere check.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. Projecting the vector onto the direction gets you parallel length squared? So maybe the OP's `len` needs to be a square root?

Comment: No, assuming the direction is normalized, there's no need to sqrt.